# Conditionally tagging a Chef node

Tags: ruby, tags, chef-infra

Using a Chef recipe I would like to have a node make an http request.  If the request fails I want to log it and have the node to tag itself with a failure code.

```
ruby_block 'connectivity_precheck' do
  block do
    Chef::Resource::RubyBlock.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::ShellOut)
    command = '/bin/curl -o /tmp/connectivity_check.txt --silent --connect-timeout 30 -k https://host.domain.com:4890'
    command_out = shell_out(command)
    if ::File.exist?('/tmp/connectivity_check.txt')
      Chef::Log.info("Connectivity confirmed.")
    else
      Chef::Log.info("Connectivity failed.")
      ???Command to Tag???
    end
  end
  action :create
end
```

Since I'm using a ruby block, I can't use "tag".  What can I do inside the ruby block to tag a node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but I would try:

```rb
run_context = Chef::RunContext.new(node, {})
run_context.node.tag("failed_tag")
```

Maybe the simpler:

```rb
node.tag("failed_tag")
```

works, too. `node` should be available within a ruby_block.